# Post action menu in iPad app should be a popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app, ipad

When I invoke the post action menu, it appears right in the middle of the screen instead of as a popup pointing to the place I tapped as I would expect:

[image]

Could it please be made into a popup pointing to the little grabby-menu-opener thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny that you reported it – I was doing some work in this area recently.

This will be fixed in the next update to the beta release (version 1.1.0.108). This will also fix the comments action menu.

[image: Now 100% more grabby]